# Why is man statfs' FUTEXFS_SUPER_MAGIC equal to bad idea (0xBAD1DEA)?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Doing `man statfs` on my system tell me that `__SWORD_TYPE f_type` can be a list of arbitrary values which are defined in header files.

Why is `FUTEXFS_SUPER_MAGIC` defined as `0xBAD1DEA`, which obviously mean "bad idea" in plain English? Is this number just a joke or is this filesystem particularly bad, dangerous...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea — and it was [removed in 2008](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=82af7aca56c67061420d618cc5a30f0fd4106b80), after being deprecated in [October 2006](https://lwn.net/Articles/207011/) by Andrew Morton:

> Apparently `FUTEX_FD` is unfixably racy and nothing uses it (or if it does, it
>   shouldn't).

(Thanks to [AlexP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/198936/alexp) for finding the deprecation message.)

Comment: Andrew Morton, announcing the scheduled removal of FUTEX_FD (November 2006), http://www.yqcomputer.com/1272_16484_1.htm: "apparently FUTEX_FD is unfixably racy and nothing uses it (or if it does, it shouldn't)".

Comment: See also the [changelog for 2.5.26](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.5/ChangeLog-2.5.26) where Al Viro complains about the state of `futex.c`.

Comment: Was there a world before 2.6?